# Rails has_many/belongs_to Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app in which I have `user`, `request`, and `proposal` models.  They're structured like this. A `user` has many `proposals` and `requests`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
  has_many :proposals
end
```

A `request` belongs to a `user` and has many `proposals`:

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :proposals
end
```

A `proposal` belongs to a `user` and a `request`.  Whatever `user` the `request` belongs to should also have the `proposal`:

```
class Proposal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :request
end
```

I have it set up like this in my `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "proposals", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "request_id"
    ...
    t.string   "status",               default: "Proposal Created"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                        null: false
  end

  add_index "proposals", ["request_id"], name: "index_proposals_on_request_id"
  add_index "proposals", ["user_id"], name: "index_proposals_on_user_id"

  create_table "requests", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "project_title"
    ...
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "requests", ["user_id"], name: "index_requests_on_user_id"
```

I have a `proposal#new`/`proposal#edit` view form in which I set the `:request` using a `hidden_field`:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :request, value: @request %>
```

Then, when I try to call the `project_title` of the `request` that has a `proposal` on the `proposal#show` page (`<%= @proposal.request.project_title %>`) it comes out as `nil`.

Can anyone help me restructure things to get this working right?  The only complicated thing I'm trying to do is, following [this blog](http://jacopretorius.net/2012/12/populating-form-values-through-a-link-in-rails.html) I'm trying to get the value of the `request` by which link is clicked.  Here's my `proposals_controller`:

```
class ProposalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_proposal, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /proposals
  def index
    @proposals = Proposal.all
  end

  # GET /proposals/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /proposals/new
  def new
    @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
    @proposal = Proposal.new
  end

  # GET /proposals/1/edit
  def edit
    @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
    @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /proposals
  def create
    @request = Request.find(params[:request_id])
    @proposal = @request.proposals.new
    @proposal.user = @request.user

    if @proposal.save
      redirect_to request_proposal_path(@request, @proposal), notice: 'Proposal was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /proposals/1
  def update
    if @proposal.update(proposal_params)
      redirect_to @proposal, notice: 'Proposal was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  # DELETE /proposals/1
  def destroy
    @proposal.destroy
    redirect_to proposals_url, notice: 'Proposal was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  def unarchive
    @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:id])
    if @proposal.update_attributes(status: "Sent to Client")
      FavoriteMailer.send_proposal_to_client(@proposal, @proposal.user).deliver_now
      flash[:notice] = "That proposal has sent to the client."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:alert] = "That proposal could not be sent right now."
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_proposal
      @proposal = Proposal.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def proposal_params
      params.require(:proposal).permit(:user_id, :request_id, :executive_summary, :situation_analysis, :strategy_online, :strategy_real_world, :strategy_credentials, :strategy_timeline, :respond_by, :timetable, :financials, :conditions, :acceptance, :status)
    end
end
```

And here are my routes:

```
get 'proposal/:request', to: 'proposals#new', as: 'new_proposal'
resources :proposals
```

Anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try doing something like this in your routes

```
   resources:requests do
     resources :proposals
   end
```

response

```
                  request_proposals GET        /requests/:request_id/proposals(.:format)                                        proposals#index
                                    POST       /requests/:request_id/proposals(.:format)                                        proposals#create
               new_request_proposal GET        /requests/:request_id/proposals/new(.:format)                                    proposals#new
              edit_request_proposal GET        /requests/:request_id/proposals/:id/edit(.:format)                               proposals#edit
                   request_proposal GET        /requests/:request_id/proposals/:id(.:format)                                    proposals#show
                                    PATCH      /requests/:request_id/proposals/:id(.:format)                                    proposals#update
                                    PUT        /requests/:request_id/proposals/:id(.:format)                                    proposals#update
                                    DELETE     /requests/:request_id/proposals/:id(.:format)                                    proposals#destroy
                           requests GET        /requests(.:format)                                                              requests#index
                                    POST       /requests(.:format)                                                              requests#create
                        new_request GET        /requests/new(.:format)                                                          requests#new
                       edit_request GET        /requests/:id/edit(.:format)                                                     requests#edit
                            request GET        /requests/:id(.:format)                                                          requests#show
                                    PATCH      /requests/:id(.:format)                                                          requests#update
                                    PUT        /requests/:id(.:format)                                                          requests#update
                                    DELETE     /requests/:id(.:format)                                                          requests#destroy
```

to make a new proposals you would do: `new_request_proposal_path(@request)`

Comment: I think it would be the other way around (proposals belong to requests). How would this change my routing links (e.g. linking to a new proposal)?

Comment: And tell proposal belongs to a request

Comment: I updated my `new` method in my `proposals_controller` to `  def new
    @request = Request.find(params[:request])
    @proposal = @request.proposals.new
    @proposal.user = @request.user
  end` but I'm still getting `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"proposals", :request_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:request_id]` when I try to load my `requests#index` (which has the link to create a proposal).

Comment: I added the requested change and everything works, except for the fact that it doesn't save any information to the database (all the fields except `user_id` and `request_id` come up `nil`.  I updated my OP to include all of my `proposals_controller`.  Any hint what's going wrong?

Comment: are you using strong params?

Comment: That I know of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130845/discussion-between-liz-and-mzaragoza).